# WPF + Kinect application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, kinect

I want to do an WPF application with Kinect. The idea is pretty simple. An app that show some images, and I will pass to the next image with the gesture that will be catched by the kinect for windows.

I saw a lot of books on internet, some codes, but I don't know how can I get started develop using Kinect sdk.

Someone can get me some help ?

Comment: Did you see this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228857/Kinect-and-WPF-Skeleton-tracking-using-the-officia

Comment: But how can put a button, get the event when my hand are in ?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect

Comment: Do you want to use the SDK, or some other source?(i can only name the SDK cause that is the only one i use)

Comment: @Lucas_Santos try [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tbh it`s simple mathematic. 
First of all you need to make your hand to be tracked so you can get data of its position and to add some nice icon to navigate. Than you can do simple math to get when the hand is over a button.

That is one way. Second way is ugly but will work :) You can bind your hand to mouse coursor and create normal buttons. As you know Windows provides all that you need to create buttons which are controller by keybord and mouse. You have all events like hover and click. When you bind your hand tracking to the mouse you can using standard libs controll the button

Third way would be combining this two methods. Hand tracking, mouse control, standard libs, with simple gesture recognition and math you can create UI like on xbox where you need to put your hand over the button for couple of seconds.

About week ago I found in google article about creating UI like in xbox but know I can't find it. Maybe I got it at home. I'll check it for you and add it if I have the url.

Flot2011 added you url to c4f to the kinect section. I'm sure that I saw there some articles about that. Just check all the pages. You can find there very interesting things with source code. For example this -> http://kinectdtw.codeplex.com/

This project is written in older version bus as you will se there are buttons. Check if there are controller by kinect, if yes just learn how to do this from the source code :)

Comment: Curse you and your thinking the same as me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! This is like the 10th question you've beaten me to=P..... But good answer